# download m3u8 link with google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, m3u8

Hi does anyone know a code to download m3u8 link using the google colab platform?

#@title ← Run    Paste m3u8 link   { display-mode: "form" }
import os
M3u8_link = "https://xex.stluserehtem.com/_v10/b75128519ad94345fa30e366fa2a7c2b459240e488a7a9c0aead948706c10e8447f5dd9a16ba6be0c80800f13976d07a866659ad31f2e00c5bac1ebcbafb84ec1933df848179752c15f95a51a192e6c46cfcc6553066d57e38edd65d8221190987f925ef5bb0a451256bccd7ed7b293d799d170ff051157bd2b3a6e82ec08529/playlist.m3u8" #@param {type:"string"}
Download_location = "/content/downle/myvideo.mp4" #@param {type:"string"}

!sudo apt install -y ffmpeg
!pip install --user m3u8downloader

!~/.local/bin/downloadm3u8 -o "$Download_location" "$M3u8_link"

used this code but got erro filename too long